# Operand should contain 1 column(s) in Mysql - Error #1241

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

I just tried the below query in mysql-

```
SELECT          booking0_.id               AS id1_6_, 
                booking0_.booking_comment  AS booking_2_6_, 
                booking0_.booking_status   AS booking_3_6_, 
                booking0_.created_by       AS created12_6_, 
                booking0_.created_date     AS created_4_6_, 
                booking0_.effective_price  AS effectiv5_6_, 
                booking0_.move_in_date     AS move_in_6_6_, 
                booking0_.payment_plan     AS payment_7_6_, 
                booking0_.property_id      AS propert13_6_, 
                booking0_.rent_end_date    AS rent_end8_6_, 
                booking0_.rent_start_date  AS rent_sta9_6_, 
                booking0_.room_id          AS room_id14_6_, 
                booking0_.room_config_id   AS room_co15_6_, 
                booking0_.security_deposit AS securit10_6_, 
                booking0_.sid              AS sid16_6_, 
                booking0_.updated_by       AS updated17_6_, 
                booking0_.updated_date     AS updated11_6_ 
FROM            oc_booking booking0_ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN mst_student student1_ 
ON              booking0_.sid=student1_.sk_student_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN oc_room_config roomconfig2_ 
ON              booking0_.room_config_id=roomconfig2_.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN oc_invoices invoices3_ 
ON              booking0_.id=invoices3_.booking_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN mst_property property4_ 
ON              booking0_.property_id=property4_.sk_property_id 
WHERE           ( 
                Concat(student1_.first_name, ' ', student1_.last_name) LIKE "%Prashant%" 
                OR  student1_.mobile LIKE "%9916630039%") 
AND             ( 
                booking0_.booking_status IN ("BOOKED" , "PENDING")) 
AND             ( 
                booking0_.room_id IS NULL) 
AND             invoices3_.is_booking_invoice=1 
AND             ( 
                invoices3_.invoice_status IN ("partialPaid" , "paid")) 
AND             roomconfig2_.current_state=("SINGLE_SHARING" , "DOUBLE_SHARING") 
and             property4_.sk_property_id=1 
ORDER BY        booking0_.updated_date DESC;
```

but I keep on getting this error:

> Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

I have referred to other answers on the same error but was unable to find the right clue.

Comment: AND             roomconfig2_.current_state=("SINGLE_SHARING" , "DOUBLE_SHARING")  IN rather than equals? I'm voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: Thanks for the help , will keep in mind these silly mistakes